# Anime with guys battling each other using small cars with weapons

Tags: crush-gear-turbo

The anime is set in a world where people duel each other by using small cars with weapons . They throw the cars into the arena and the cars attack each other. I distinctly remember a blue colored car and I think that is the hero's.

Comment: Do you remember when you saw it? In what language? Can you describe the hero? Right now the question doesn't contain enough information.

Comment: I saw it in English, about 8-9 years back. The hero has this blue colored car . I think he wears a white jacket . That's most I can remember

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you're referring to [**Crush Gear Turbo**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crush_Gear_Turbo)

[image: CGT]
<sup>From http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/92/CrushGearTurbo-Logo-DVDSrc.jpg</sup>

[image: CGT2]
<sup>From http://de.crushgear.wikia.com/wiki/Datei:Crush_Gear_Turbo_2.png</sup>

> The *hero's* name is Kouya Marino and your description of his appearance matches to an extent.

Comment: Yes. This is the anime . Thank you for your answer.